# Syncfusion Line chart does not plot line and shows multiple points on Xaxis for same data

Tags: wpf, syncfusion

I am plotting 3 different lines with the following data.

```
x10:0  y10:65000 x20:0 y20:10000 x30:0 y30:7000 

x11:1 y11:40000 x21:1 y21:61000 x31:1 y31:13000
```

and so on....

But the chart has 3 different x's for x1, x2, x3 respectively and it does not connect y1 and y11(the line) and it shows that the StrokeThickness of chart elements is 2.0 and stroke shows the color I specified. (All above values taken from VS debug)

I did not use any MVVM, but set the datasource, BindingPathsY, BindingPathX via event handlers.

Is there any extra function I need to call if I am not using MVVM for the strokes to appear?(Similar to the canvas stroke.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points were misleading.

I was creating a new instance of collection for x10,y10 x11,y11 and x12,y12, which was the problem. So it created another set of points, for same data.

Instead I changed the code so that I create only one collection for 3 different graphs.

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect same X-axis points values as a straight line, then we need to use the Linear axis (NumaricalAxis, DateTimeAxis, LogarithmicAxis) instead of using CategoryAxis for Chart Primary Axis.

Regards,

M.Sheik